# SQL Row Value Based on Rules

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day all,

[image]

As you can see from the image above, I have 2 columns; Expected and Actual.

The Expected Column was inserted manually to show what I need. The Actual Column is my attempt at matching it.

I need to be able to Count by one, when ever there is a new "function" added to the test.

But i need to Actual column to also be able to understand when the function has been duplicated.

ALL data that you see in the picture is all the data I have to work with with the exception of the Expected Column, please imagine that column isn't there.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your logic that makes you want TestID 1 to be 4? How would you like to group your rows? Also, just to be clear, you're desired output is for the actual to match the expected?

Comment: Every new function Id in the query will increment the value. Yes the desired outcome is to have the actual equal the expected

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. Looking at your data set, you have 4 rows with funcID of 2, 2 of which have an expected value of 1 while the other 2 have an expected value of 2. Could you please explain what sets these 2 sets apart?

Comment: The only thing that I can make them set apart is that Parameter Has an ID FK to Function.  So function ID 2 has 2 parameters 2 and 3.  Knowing the number of parameters per function is the only way i can logically come up with seperation?  Thoughts?

Comment: Have you solved your issue? If no, please add sample data as text leaving only columns that affect your expected column. Also it's unclear why you are expecting values `1-1-2-2` for rows `1-4` when `TestID` and `FuncID` don't change. And what SQL version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by building a column that counts how many params the row's function has.

The orderNum will just have to be inserted manually

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY q.[ID]) AS [Row],
    q.[OrderNum],
    (SELECT count(B.[ID]) FROM [dbo].[Parameter] AS B WHERE B.[FunctionID] = q.[FuncID]) [NumOfParams],
    q.[FunctionPath], q.[Function], q.[Parameter], q.[Data]
FROM q
```